# Cannot remove inherited permissions in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I follow the normal steps which brings me to the usual screen:

[image]

However, if I chose any of the two options, and then get to OK in the next stage I will get the following error:

[image]

What's going on here? I never saw this problem previously?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by changing the permissions of a security product?

Comment: I'm trying to delete a folder which does not let me deleting it otherwise. It's not used by any software it has some sort of strange permissioning limitations I have not seen before and I'm struggling to change them

Comment: @afora377 What makes your think it isn't used? Do you even know [what cef is and what it is used for](Chromium Embedded Framework)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you can try to get the ability to change permissions on the folder:

1. Take ownership of the folder. You can do this on the Owner tab of the Advanced Security dialog box. Be sure to mark "change child objects" so that the change affects everything in the folder.
2. If step 1 doesn't work, try it again but logged in with the built-in Administrator account.
3. If *that* doesn't work, try it booted into Safe Mode. In this mode only a minimal set of system services are running, so if you're getting stopped by a process that's blocking your changes, it might not be running in Safe Mode and therefore unable to block your change.

Comment: This is the answer (bullet point 3). Can somebody accept it as I dont have enough privileges for this. Ta

Comment: @afora377 You already accepted it. You'll be able to up vote once you get 125 reputation.